# Installing pytest for pypy

Tags: apt, python, pip

How do I install pytest to be used in pypy? Already installed with standard python

```
arkadiusz@pc:~$ pip install pytest
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytest in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py>=1.4.29 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
```

but cannot run

```
arkadiusz@pc:~$ pypy -m pip install pytest
/usr/bin/pypy: No module named pip
```

cannot install pip

```
arkadiusz@pc:~$ pypy -m ensurepip
ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python.

Python modules For the system python are usually handled by dpkg and apt-get.

    apt-get install pypy-<module name>

Install the python-pip package to use pip itself.  Using pip together
with the system python might have unexpected results for any system installed
module, so use it on your own risk, or make sure to only use it in virtual
```

The ensurepip suggests using apt-get but apt does not have pip or pytest for pypy.

```
arkadiusz@pc:~$ sudo apt-get install pypy
pypy                pypy-genty          pypy-rply
pypy-appdirs        pypy-idna           pypy-setuptools
pypy-attr           pypy-ipaddress      pypy-six
pypy-bs4            pypy-iso8601        pypy-sqlparse
pypy-dev            pypy-lib            pypy-tk
pypy-doc            pypy-lib-testsuite  pypy-unidecode
pypy-dulwich        pypy-mutagen        pypy-wand
pypy-enum34         pypy-pkg-resources  pypy-zmq
pypy-fastimport     pypy-pretend        
pypy-flaky          pypy-pyasn1
```

output of dpkg

```
ii  pypy                                                        5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04                                          amd64        fast alternative implementation of Python - PyPy interpreter
ii  pypy-dev                                                    5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04                                          all          header files for PyPy (an alternative Python interpreter)
ii  pypy-doc                                                    5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04                                          all          developer Documentation for PyPy (an alternative Python interpreter)
ii  pypy-lib:amd64                                              5.1.2+dfsg-1~16.04                                          amd64        standard library for PyPy (an alternative Python interpreter)
ii  pypy-pkg-resources                                          20.7.0-1                                                    all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
ii  pypy-setuptools                                             20.7.0-1                                                    all          PyPy Distutils Enhancements
```

Comment: Edited. @Junaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wget get-pip.py script using

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Run the script

```
sudo pypy get-pip.py
```

Now run

```
pypy -m pip install pytest
```